# Transform data by Twitter

Tags: twitter

I'm working on my senior project which has some data and I need to send it by twitter.
How to send this data by twitter dynamically?
Is it need a server or not?

Thanks

Comment: I assume that "sending data by twitter" means "posting status updates on twitter"?

Answer (score 0):

You can send it by Twitter API, by [POST statuses/update](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update) service. Instead of dealing with Twitter API directly, you can use some library instead, depending on the language you're using (here' [a nice one for Ruby](https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter). You don't need server.